# Fusion table layer filtering based on polygon

Tags: dictionary, filtering, polygon, layer, google-fusion-tables

I've a fusion table map example with 5 layers given in this link : http://jsfiddle.net/ju2Re/

I want to filter the layers such that,

first I select a layer using dropdown : Office hierarchy > Zone > Bagalkot

Now I want to select the 220 KV stations only inside that polygon using the select box.

Please anyone help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have the information which layer is selected, and now you generate a `WHERE` clause. Just apply the where clause to the selected layer only.

Comment: @Odi Can u please give the code snippet to generate `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Which part of my code to be edited to add `WHERE` clause? Please help...

Comment: Okay I checked your tables, it's a little bit more complicated than I first thought. You have your data over several tables. I hoped you could simply do an `ST_INTERSECTS` to define from which area you want your data. But this does not work over 2 tables. What about adding the information in which "zone" each "station" is, so you could actually add it to the where clause? Therefore I would simply add another column to your "station" table with the zone id. Then you can simply create a `WHERE` clause like `where "Station Name" = <name> and "Zone ID" = <id>`

Comment: But in which part of my code I add `WHERE` clause? I am bit confused. I also want filter the same way by Circles, Divisions in dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this natively with fusion tables (at least
not right now).  The only query that can be used for "point in
polygon" analysis is:
[ST_INTERSECTS(,
)](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#Select)
.

That takes a geometry as one argument, but the only values of  are:
- 
-

So if you have one point, you can use it to define a small circle and
use ST_INTERSECTS with a polygon, but that won't  work for multiple
points.

With the current size of your tables you can use GViz to retrieve the
data from FusionTables and analyze it in the browser.

[Proof of Concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_point_in_polyA.html) (only works for "Geographical Heirarchy"/"District")

The code adds a "Contains" method to google.maps.Polygon, then iterates through the markers, displaying them if they are contained in the "activePolygon".

[Proof of Concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_point_in_polyC.html) should handle all the cases that have data

Comment: This is a great idea. But can I filter for "Office Hierarchy > Zone/Circle/Division" using same concept? Please explain the code given in [Proof of Concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_point_in_polyA.html)

Comment: Yes you can filter for all those things using the same mechanism, I just didn't.  Added a brief explanation of the concept.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I use my customized info window as in http://jsfiddle.net/ju2Re/ with this code?

Comment: Personally, I would remove a bunch of your existing code first.  I am not going to write your code for you, but may (if and when time permits) make a more functional proof of concept.  You seem to be missing data to complete your filtering hierarchy, or am I missing something?

Comment: And for me to spend any more time on it you would to make your fusion tables downloadable (so I can make my own copy).

Comment: I made my tables downloadable. Plz help.